# Does JSF support form based security

Tags: jsf-2

I followed this tutorial 
[security](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/security.html)In this tutorial it is mentioned that add something like this for form based security

```
<form action="j_security_check" method=post>
    <p>username: <input type="text" name="j_username"></p>
    <p>password: <input type="password" name="j_password"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
```

But in JSF form i have no action attributr in h:form, which i set to **j_security_check**.  Also use of j_username and j_password is also necessary to use in JSF to provide form based security?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this action URL and field names are mandatory for [form based authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html#bncbq). This is specified in the servlet specification. You can just use it as-is in a JSF page. The only difference is that the form submit and authentication is fully handled by the container, not by JSF. You don't need to worry about this.

If you however want more finer grained control over the form submit process, or want to utilize JSF builtin validation and ajax powers and so on, then you can always takeover it by [programmatic authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html) in a JSF managed bean. For this you have to use [`HttpServletRequest#login()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in the action method. The authentication is still handled by the container.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{login.username}" required="true" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{login.password}" required="true" />
    <h:commandButton value="login" action="#{login.submit}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

with

```
public String submit() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

    try {
        request.login(username, password);
        return "home?faces-redirect-true";
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Unknown login", null));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: HHm thanks but when we use `request.login(username, password);`, then how JSF verify it. Like i enter basit(user) and basit(password). Do i need to set the username password somewhere in the glassfish server or in database? Means how request.login() works? Thanks

Comment: Just the same way as form based authentication. The only difference is that you invoke it programmatically instead of submitting to `j_security_check` with `j_username` and `j_password`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I implemented j_security_check (Container Managed Security) for my JSF application running in Websphere 7. Unfortunately, the servlet api version I'm using does not have

```
request.login()
```

A Login Filter class was created to intercept j_security_check calls. The ResponseWrapper remembers the URL to be redirected after login.

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
        private static String loginPage = "login.xhtml"; // read it from init config
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // create wrapper
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        MyWrapper myRes = new MyWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
        // call authentication
        chain.doFilter(request, myRes);
        // check for login error
                String redirectURL = myRes.getOriginalRedirect();
          if (StringUtils.isBlank(redirectURL) || redirectURL.contains(loginPage)) {
                   myRes.setOriginalRedirect(homePage);
              }
    myRes.sendMyRedirect();

}
    class MyWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
        String originalRedirect;

        public MyWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
            // just store location, don’t send redirect to avoid
            // committing response
            originalRedirect = location;
        }

        // use this method to send redirect after modifying response
        public void sendMyRedirect() throws IOException {
            super.sendRedirect(originalRedirect);
        }

        public String getOriginalRedirect() {
            return originalRedirect;
        }

        public void setOriginalRedirect(String originalRedirect) {
            this.originalRedirect = originalRedirect;
        }


    }
```

The web.xml looks as follows.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.servlet.filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>RequestJSFFilter</filter-name
        <filter-class>com.servlet.filter.RequestJSFFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RequestJSFFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Another filter that intercepts all the *.xhtml and directs to the login.xhtml. In the login.xhtml, the form can look as follows

```
<form action="j_security_check" method=post>
    <p>username: <input type="text" name="j_username"></p>
    <p>password: <input type="password" name="j_password"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is apparently Websphere specific. A filter can namely not be mapped directly on `/j_security_check` as this will be handled by the container far before the webapp-specific filters are entered. Your approach will fail in at least Tomcat, JBoss and Glassfish.

Comment: I agree that. I have been searching for a solution that works with Websphere. Unfortunately, I could not find one. Hence posted this that can help someone.