# What is the JSF 2.0 code for handling user authentication?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, authentication

The standard tutorials for J2EE 6 show the handling of user authentication as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
         <tr>
            <td align="right">Username:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="j_username">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td align="right">Password:&nbsp;</td>
             <td>
                <input type="password" name="j_password">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td>
                 <input type="submit" value="Login">
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The approach uses the special container function "j_security_check" with special fields "j_username" and "j_password".

*** Would this be possible to do in JSF 2.0 ?

* Are the j_username/j_password fields available after successful authentication? More precisely, how do I identify the user after they have authenticated?**

Any simple, example code snippets would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use the above code; have a look at the [ExternalContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getExternalContext%28%29) for accessing container-managed credentials.

Comment: I should add that my motivation for this is to leverage all the look & feel stuff in my application that I get my JSF templates, Primefaces themes etc. By "dumbing down" to HTML as above, I have to do more work :-) That is, I'm trying to avoid having to work out all the CSS references, class tags etc and manually construct a HTML login page that looks and feels like the rest of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Would this be possible to do in JSF 2.0 ?*

Yes. It's after all just a bunch of HTML and the container is the one who's doing the authentication, not JSF itself. An alternative is programmatic login by [`HttpServletRequest#login()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). This allows you to use a fullworthy JSF form with JSF based validation, ajax fanciness and all on em. See also this answer for a kickoff example: [Does JSF support form based security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686547/does-jsf-support-form-based-security)

---

> *Are the j_username/j_password fields available after successful authentication? More precisely, how do I identify the user after they have authenticated?*

Only the username is in JSF context available by [`ExternalContext#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRemoteUser%28%29) and in views by `#{request.remoteUser}`. The password is not available for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

1. Quite some time ago I tried to accomplish a jsf (1.2) login page with spring security. However as I did not succeed I finally gave up and did it with a "regular" jsp as you're doing it above.
2. You can identify the current user by injecting the current SessionContext into your EJB:

   ```
   @Resource
   SessionContext sessionContext;
   public void doSth() {
       log.info("The current user's name is: " 
          + sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName() );
   }
   ```

   You can do the same on HttpServletRequest:

   ```
   request.getUserPrincipal();
   ```

   Or from FacesContext:

   ```
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
   ```